# verify if svn repository exists with svn info + grep

Tags: bash, svn, grep

Trying to write script to detect if the current folder has an svn checkout. running this command in a folder that is does NOT have any svn files:

```
svn info
```

outputs the expected:

```
svn: E155007: '/home/prog1/Desktop/deploy' is not a working copy
```

using | grep

```
svn info | grep E155007
```

it returns:

```
svn: E155007: '/home/prog1/Desktop/deploy' is not a working copy
```

(it is not highlinting the matching text with red)

If I change the grep with this:

```
svn info | grep A155007
```

it still returns

```
svn: E155007: '/home/prog1/Desktop/deploy' is not a working copy
```

Subversion command-line client, version 1.8.8.
I understand that I can check if a .svn folder exists, but it is strange why svn info, in case where no working copy is found, can't be used with | grep.

Any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Aren'y you confusing a working copy with a repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
svn: E155007: '/home/prog1/Desktop/deploy' is not a working copy
```

is an error message, usually it's print on stderr, to check

```
svn info 2>/dev/null
```

writes nothing on terminal because stderr redirected to `/dev/null`

```
svn info 2>&1 | grep --color E155007
```

now, duplicating pipe input to stderr, should be colorized.

by default stdout (file descriptor 1) and stderr (file descriptor 2) are writting to tty.

Without redirection the stderr is still writting to tty without being filtered by `grep`.

Comment: it redirects stderr (fd2) to the same file as stdout (fd1), see [manual for more info](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)